# Calculating field and applying floor/ceiling?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am trying to find a way to achieve what is showing in the below table. My data has timestamp and value columns and I want to calculate the requiredValue column. The explanation below describes the calculations I have  performed.

[image]

```
let initialValue = 5;
datatable (timestamp: datetime, value: int)
[
    '2023-01-01', 10, 
    '2023-01-02', 20, 
    '2023-01-03', 30, 
    '2023-01-04', -10, 
    '2023-01-05', 40, 
    '2023-01-06', -50
]
```

I want to calculate the requiredValue column using KQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [`scan` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator).

for example:

```
let _floor = 10;
let _ceiling = 25;
datatable(timestamp: datetime, value: int)
[
    datetime(2023-01-01), 10, 
    datetime(2023-01-02), 20, 
    datetime(2023-01-03), 30, 
    datetime(2023-01-04), -10, 
    datetime(2023-01-05), 40, 
    datetime(2023-01-06), -50
]
| order by timestamp asc
| scan declare(required_value: int = 0) with (
    step s1: true => required_value = case(
                                          s1.required_value + value > _ceiling, _ceiling,
                                          s1.required_value + value < _floor, _floor,
                                          s1.required_value + value
                                      );
)
```

| timestamp | value | required_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 10 | 10 |
| 2023-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 20 | 25 |
| 2023-01-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 30 | 25 |
| 2023-01-04 00:00:00.0000000 | -10 | 15 |
| 2023-01-05 00:00:00.0000000 | 40 | 25 |
| 2023-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 | -50 | 10 |